# Problem in passing value to parser argument

Tags: python, parsing, pytorch

Running my code including this line:

```
def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='test with parser')
    parser.add_argument("--model", type=str, default= "E:\Script\weights\resnext101.pth")
```

I got this error:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'E:\\Script\\weights\resnext101.pth'
```

What is the error for and how I can fix it?

Comment: what is `parser`? where does it come from?

Comment: @Anentropic , the op just updated.

Comment: if I copy and paste your function and call it I get no error. this implies something in the rest of the code doesn't like the value `'E:\\Script\\weights\resnext101.pth'` for that arg

Comment: Error 22 is normally an invalid path error, are you sure your path is correct?

Comment: @Anthony1223 , The file resides in the path. But I'm afraid if I used correct syntax.. I'm working on Windows if it helps.

Comment: No error for me.

Comment: This path will be read by torch.load(). My case is as this one https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/torch-load-path-filenotfounderror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory/118532  but none of solutions work for me.

Comment: You can try to use a raw string or triple quotation marks, have you tried opening the file using python normally (Open) to see if it's an issue with pytorch or python?

Comment: I checked with another weight file with .pt extension and have not got this error. Is there any .pt weight file for resnet?

Comment: Use a raw string, or use `/` as the path separator. The problem is that `\S` and `\w` are not special escape sequences for `str` literals, and so are left unchanged. `\r`, however, is the escape sequence for a carriage return.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't passing a path ending with the name `resnext101.pth`; you are passing a path ending with the name `weights␍esnext101.pth`, which contains a literal carriage return.

Use a raw string literal to protect *all* backslashes from expansion, regardless of the character that follows the backslash.

```
parser.add_argument("--model", type=str, default= r"E:\Script\weights\resnext101.pth")
```